# C Read binary file to a buffer

Tags: c, binary, buffer

I'm trying to create a simple VM that can read in a binary file, follow the instructions in the binary (4 words each instruction - 32 bit), and then output the result after following all instructions.

I'm currently in the first phase of my project , and am trying to use fread/fopen to read in the contents of my file into a buffer. For the most part the code is similar to the example given on fread for cplusplus.com, however I want to find a way to break my file into 4 words at a time. I've never worked at such a low level before, and am having problems finding out whether or not I am doing this correctly, and was hoping someone here could help me make sure I'm breaking the file up into 4 words correctly.

```
FILE * pFile;
long lSize;
unsigned char * buffer;
size_t result;

  pFile = fopen ( "test.bin" , "rb" );

  if (pFile==NULL) {fprint("error, file null")}

  fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
  lSize = ftell (pFile);
  rewind (pFile);

  // allocate memory to contain the whole file:
  buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc (sizeof(unsigned char)*lSize);
  if (buffer == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}

  // copy the file into the buffer:
  result = fread (buffer, 4,lSize,pFile); //The error is here, if I use 1 instead of 4 there is no error output but I am not sure this would properly break the file into 4 words read at a time.
  if (result != lSize) {fputs ("Reading error",stderr); exit (3);}
   printf("%ld\n",lSize);
```

Right now when I run this I am getting an error, unless I change the number in the line that I commented back to 1.

Comment: To learn to code C, you really shouldn't follow cplusplus.com ; that's really a website about C++, not C. (and the quality of the information there is a constant cause for dispute).

Comment: What *kind* of error do you get? Did you remember to divide `lSize` by `4` when reading 4-byte elements?

Comment: I get the "Reading error" output from my final error check @EOF

Comment: `man fread: [...]On  success,  fread()  and  fwrite() return the number of items read or written.  This number equals the number of bytes transferred only  when size  is 1.[...]`

Comment: `lSize` is the number of bytes in the file. So your `fread` is trying to read `4*lSize` bytes. Which of course is too much. Which in itself won't cause an error, just reads less than requested. But as pointed out `fread` returns the number of **items** read not the number of bytes. So your `fread` should really be `fread(fd, 4, lSize/4);`. Assuming the file size really is an exact multiple of 4.

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C! C is **not** C++. And using `sizeof(char)` is plain nonsense, as it is **defined** by the standard to yield `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Representing a binary file as a buffer is something that your OS can do for you; the man page of [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) has a working example in C89 (so it's antique):

```
       fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
```

...

```
       if (fstat(fd, &sb) == -1)           /* To obtain file size */
           handle_error("fstat");

       offset = atoi(argv[2]);
       pa_offset = offset & ~(sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE) - 1);
           /* offset for mmap() must be page aligned */
```

...

```
       if (argc == 4) {
           length = atoi(argv[3]);
           if (offset + length > sb.st_size)
               length = sb.st_size - offset;
                   /* Can't display bytes past end of file */

       } else {    /* No length arg ==> display to end of file */
           length = sb.st_size - offset;
       }

       addr = mmap(NULL, length + offset - pa_offset, PROT_READ,
                   MAP_PRIVATE, fd, pa_offset);
       if (addr == MAP_FAILED)
           handle_error("mmap");
```

Now, `addr` points to a memory region containing the input file in your process' address space.

This will save you reading the whole file before the start of processing, as your OS can automatically read only the parts of the file you're actually accessing without further ado.

Also, since you're writing a VM (whatever that means to you!) you should be aware of typical process memory structures, so learning what `mmap` does is an excellent excercise.